# How to create child theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have enfold theme installed in my Wordpress site. i have tried following things

1)i have create one folder named - enfold-child
   2)i have create two files in that folder
      1) style.css
      2) functions.php
      3)screenshot of parent theme enfold

now i have placed code in style.css like this

```
/*
Theme Name: Enfold
Description: <strong>A superflexible and responsive Business Theme by Kriesi</strong> - <br/> Update notifications available on twitter and facebook:<br/> <a href='http://twitter.com/kriesi'>Follow me on twitter</a><br/> - <a href='http://www.facebook.com/pages/Kriesi/333648177216'>Join the Facebook Group</a>
Version: 2.2
Author: Kriesi
Author URI: http://www.kriesi.at
License: Themeforest Split Licence
License URI: -
Theme URI: www.kriesi.at/themes/enfold/
Template: enfold
*/
```

but when i am open themes in admin panel this message displays in enfold child - This child theme requires its parent theme, Enfold.

so where does i mistaken

my enfold parent theme has code like this

```
- /*
Theme Name: Enfold
Description: <strong>A superflexible and responsive Business Theme by Kriesi</strong> - <br/> Update notifications available on twitter and facebook:<br/> <a href='http://twitter.com/kriesi'>Follow me on twitter</a><br/> - <a href='http://www.facebook.com/pages/Kriesi/333648177216'>Join the Facebook Group</a>
Version: 2.2
Author: Kriesi
Author URI: http://www.kriesi.at
License: Themeforest Split Licence
License URI: -
Theme URI: www.kriesi.at/themes/enfold/
*/


/*
* PLEASE DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!
* 
* This file is only in your themefolder for WordPress to recognize basic theme data like name and version
* CSS Rules in this file will not be used by the theme. 
* Instead use the custom.css file that is located in your themes /css/ folder to add your styles. 
* You can copy a style rule from any of your css files and paste it in custom.css and
* it will override the original style. If you just want to add small css snippets you might also
* want to consider to add it to the designated CSS option field in your themes backend at: Theme Options->Styling
*/
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add code in style.css of child theme like as follows

```
/*
 Theme Name:     your child theme name
 Theme URI:      http://example.com/child-theme-url/
 Description:    your Child Theme desc
 Author:         your author name
 Author URI:     http://example.com
 Template:       enfold
 Version:        1.0.0
*/

/* =Imports styles from the parent theme
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
@import url('../enfold/style.css');
```

Template : is the your parent theme folder name.
I hope this will help to resolve your problem.

Comment: i have did this but message not changed

Comment: put the Template name  is the your parent theme folder name

Comment: can you put site url here?

Comment: please check your parent theme style.css file

Answer (score 2):

you need not to do anything, you can download ready made enfold child theme.. just copy following link and paste into your browser's address bar...

**https://kriesi.at/files/enfold-child.zip**

if you want to create custom one, then check following link.

**https://vimeo.com/67221517**

I hope you will like it.. :)

Answer (score 1):

**You need to include `Template: enfold` in style.css of your child theme.**

See this official wordpress docs link of Child theme http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes & read especially this part:

> ....You can change each of these lines to suit your theme. The only
>   required lines are the Theme Name, and the Template. The Template is
>   the directory name of the parent theme. In this case, the parent theme
>   is the TwentyThirteen theme, so the Template is twentythirteen, which
>   is the name of the directory where the TwentyThirteen theme resides....

Comment: I have did this but message not changed